# Is it possible to have a monoid with a proper class as the collection of elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question if it possible for us to have, for example, a monoid(any algebraic structure really) with a class as the collection of the elements, instead of a set.

An example would be the class of sets and set union as addition. Clearly, it is closed under the operation, is associative and it has an identity element, so it is a monoid. Is it possible to say so?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory. I'm not putting it in the answer proper since I don't have time to write about it in an appropriate way, but it's one starting point for approaching the "set, class, hyperclass, ..." situation in a reasonably-satisfying way, both in set theory and category theory, and you may find it worthwhile.

Comment: Surely the "collection" of arrows of a one-object category often constitutes such a "monoid"? This suggests that it is not only possible but also *necessary* to be able to talk about such things. (I'm not giving this as an answer, because although I don't lack time, I do lack competence to write about it appropriately!) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as with groups, rings, topological spaces, etc., the answer is "technically no but sorta yes."

- **Technically no**: Well, a monoid (for example) is *defined to be* a **set** together with a binary operation such that [stuff]. So, sethood is built right in.
- **Sorta yes**: But we can clearly talk$^*$ about "class-monoids" - namely, *classes* with a binary *class* operation such that [stuff]. And the "basic theory" of these objects will be unchanged.

  - $^*$Well, actually [usual set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) *can't* talk directly about classes. So you either have to [upgrade your foundations a bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) or avoid *quantifying over* classes (e.g. you can't say "all class monoids ...") and restrict attention to more-or-less specific examples (essentially, "treat the 'definable' class monoids on a case-by-case basis"). But this is a more minor point for now, so ignore it.

The rub of course is my claim that "the "basic theory" of these objects will be unchanged" - what precisely constitutes the "basic theory?" Or, phrased another way, when can we conclude that a fact about *set-sized objects* also holds for *class-sized objects*? This starts to take us a bit into set theory and category theory, and I won't try to give an answer here, except to say that $(i)$ there is genuinely content around this point, so it's not a stupid distinction (and in particular the **right** answer to your question is "no"), but $(ii)$ you'll rarely run into an actual point of set/class difference if you're not actively searching for it. This isn't too satisfying, but it's the situation.